# Android Asset Studio import icons from zip file into Android Studio

Tags: android

I have used Android Asset Studio to generate some icons. I have downloaded the zip files. Is there a way to bulk import the icons (in all their various resolutions) into my project in Android Studio. Currently I'm copying and pasting one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First I found that the images files can be copied into the project file structure (i.e. main\res\drawable-hdpi etc) and then Android Studio automatically detects them and includes them in the project.

So using Windows 7, I was able to unzip the Android Asset Studio zip file and then use robocopy to copy the *.png files and preserve the directory structure.

robocopy "C:\Temp\ic_myicon\res" ".\res" *.png /S